# imposition pdf via ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, imposition

there are lots of solution, like [Quite Imposing](http://www.quite.com/imposing/). My thoughts, can we use ghostscipt do similar thing. say,
- split pages into several ps files
- using postscript run command, insert those ps file into a temple
- transfer ps template into pdf (via ghostscript again)

here comes my experiment template,

```
%!
/Times-Roman findfont 14 scalefont setfont
% Page 1
save
  /showpage {} bind def
  72 200 translate
  (BBB001.ps) run
restore
72 680 moveto (This is a text on page 1) show
72 200 translate
72 100 moveto (this page 1) show
showpage

72 100 moveto
(this page 2) show
showpage
```

after changing above into pdf can't see BBB001.ps, where am I wrong? or it doesn't work completely!

[update]
I finially get it work, turn BBB001.ps to BBB001.eps.

Answer (score 0):

OK first, don't go to PostScript and back to PDF, that's going to lose all kinds of quality.

If you want to do page imposition, then you need to look into the PDF interpreter, which is itself written in PostScript, and tweak it at a fairly high level. Basically you just need to not do the initgraphics/eraspage/showpage dance for each page.

You might like to look at my answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545382/ghostscript-for-pdf-how-to-fit-4-pages-into-1/30546987#30546987)

Its not really possible to say why you can't see 'BBB001.ps' because I have no idea what's in that PostScript program. If it contains a showpage, then it will render that page eject it, erase the page and then do the remaining part of the program (the text "This is a text on page 1" etc) eject that page, go on to do the next page.

Comment: ideed, from pdf -> eps -> pdf, the quality become worse.